# Does running `find . -type d -exec chmod` in the root directory causes problem?

Tags: command-line, find

I accidentally ran

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

inside the home directory after using `cd ~`. Is there any side effect when running this command inside `~` or `/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most directories in Linux file system have the same permissions `755`, but not all, so it could be a problem.

If the above command is executed in your home directory `~` some tools like `openssh-client` can complain about too open permissions, because the directory `~/.ssh` must have `700` permissions, which means your private keys are indeed private...

The situation is the same if you run the command in the root directory `/` - even worse, probably, this will damage the system. The good news is, if you run the above command within the root directory, without `sudo` (or while you are not logged-in as root), you don't have enough permissions to do the changes system wide. So you will have a trouble only with the directories where you have enough permissions to make a mess - most likely this is your home directory `~`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about ~/.ssh.

Comment: You are welcome, @MaXi32!